# Websphere Liberty profile AdminCenter page not loading

Tags: solaris, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I have downloaded the latest stable WLP runtime with JAVA EE7 for solaris environment.

```
Version : 16.0.0.3
```

The zip file is extracted and profile is created. AdminCenter installed by using below command:

```
.\installUtility install adminCenter-1.0
```

**Server.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="server1">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <quickStartSecurity userName="admin" userPassword="adminpwd" />  
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>json-1.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}PjsyNjEfbm1s" />    


    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
          httpPort="9060"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

The WAS service also started. In Browser, after providing the credentials, it shows blank page. I'm unable to view any errors in the log.The log message is given below:

```
********************************************************************************
product = WebSphere Application Server 16.0.0.3 (wlp-1.0.14.cl160320160831-1555)
wlp.install.dir = /home/wlp/wlp/
java.home = /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre
java.version = 1.8.0_05
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.8.0_05-b13)
os = SunOS (5.11; amd64) (en_US)
process = 1894@solaris
********************************************************************************
[1/3/17 7:02:31:377 UTC] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server server1 has been launched.
[1/3/17 7:02:31:407 UTC] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/16.0.0.3/lafiles/en.html
[1/3/17 7:02:33:346 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[1/3/17 7:02:33:468 UTC] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 2.347 seconds
[1/3/17 7:02:34:007 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[1/3/17 7:02:34:570 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreateTask    I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.043 seconds.
[1/3/17 7:02:34:771 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready.
[1/3/17 7:02:34:973 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9060.
[1/3/17 7:02:34:977 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 9443.
[1/3/17 7:02:35:026 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[1/3/17 7:02:35:360 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[1/3/17 7:02:35:361 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[1/3/17 7:02:35:362 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[1/3/17 7:02:35:817 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.ui.internal.v1.pojo.POJOLoaderService             I CWWKX1015I: FILE persistence layer initialized for the Admin Center.
[1/3/17 7:02:35:821 UTC] 0000000f com.ibm.ws.ui.internal.v1.pojo.PlainTextLoaderService        I CWWKX1063I: FILE persistence layer initialized for the Admin Center tool data loader.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:088 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsp-2.3, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, json-1.0, adminCenter-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, jaxrs-2.0, restConnector-1.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, el-3.0].
[1/3/17 7:02:36:088 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 2.848 seconds.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:088 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server server1 is ready to run a smarter planet.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:454 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: IBMJMXConnectorREST.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:456 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module IBMJMXConnectorREST has been bound to default_host.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:456 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://10.95.238.96:9060/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[1/3/17 7:02:36:458 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.RESTAppListener         I CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://10.95.238.96:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[1/3/17 7:02:36:459 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.RESTAppListener         I CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://10.95.238.96:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[1/3/17 7:02:36:599 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ibm/api.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:599 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module ibm/api has been bound to default_host.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:600 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://10.95.238.96:9060/ibm/api/
[1/3/17 7:02:36:637 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Server Config Tool.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:637 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Server Config Tool has been bound to default_host.
[1/3/17 7:02:36:637 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://10.95.238.96:9060/ibm/adminCenter/serverConfig-1.0/
[1/3/17 7:02:37:049 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Explore Tool.
[1/3/17 7:02:37:050 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Explore Tool has been bound to default_host.
[1/3/17 7:02:37:050 UTC] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://10.95.238.96:9060/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0/
[1/3/17 7:02:37:183 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Admin Center.
[1/3/17 7:02:37:184 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Admin Center has been bound to default_host.
[1/3/17 7:02:37:184 UTC] 00000017 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://10.95.238.96:9060/adminCenter/
[1/3/17 7:04:00:203 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[1/3/17 7:04:00:205 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/adminCenter
[1/3/17 7:04:00:212 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[1/3/17 7:04:00:222 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.jsp                                               I JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
[1/3/17 7:04:00:241 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[1/3/17 7:04:00:281 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /* in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:00:282 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /dojo/* in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:00:282 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /login/* in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:00:282 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /login.jsp in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:00:283 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /fonts/HelvNeueRomanforIBM.otf in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:00:283 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /ibm_security_logout in application com.ibm.ws.ui, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[1/3/17 7:04:04:191 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.ui] [/adminCenter] [/login.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[1/3/17 7:04:04:400 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must use either different key or iv for GCM encryption com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FileServletWrapper.writeResponseToClient 689" at ffdc_17.01.03_07.04.04.0.log
[1/3/17 7:04:09:486 UTC] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.ui] [/adminCenter] [/toolbox.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[1/3/17 7:04:09:535 UTC] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/api
[1/3/17 7:04:09:536 UTC] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[1/3/17 7:04:09:553 UTC] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.rest.handler] [/ibm/api] [RESTProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[1/3/17 7:04:09:612 UTC] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.ui.internal.v1.pojo.POJOLoaderService             I CWWKX1029I: The Admin Center default toolbox for user admin loaded.
[1/3/17 7:04:09:613 UTC] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.ui.internal.v1.pojo.POJOLoaderService             I CWWKX1000I: The Admin Center default catalog loaded.
```

Kindly guide me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like issue in Solaris JVM http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-known-issues-2157115.html , try to "Disable the GCM implementation from the OracleUcrypto provider by adding the "Cipher.AES/GCM/NoPadding" string to the disabledServices section in its provider configuration file, for example, <java-home>/lib/security/ucrypto-solaris.cfg." Or change to IBM JVM bundled with Liberty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine.

Comment: I've provided it as an answer, so you can accept it, if it solved your issues :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like issue in [Solaris JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-known-issues-2157115.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml) , try to:

> Disable the GCM implementation from the OracleUcrypto provider by
>   adding the "Cipher.AES/GCM/NoPadding" string to the disabledServices
>   section in its provider configuration file, for example,
>   /lib/security/ucrypto-solaris.cfg.

Or install JVM that is available in WebSphere Application Server product installation files (downloadable separately from Passport Advantage).

Comment: good find on this config option, but the second part of your answer implies there is a JVM bundled with Liberty? this is not true

Comment: @AndyGuibert - ahh you're right... JVM can be bundled only for Win and Linux, not Solaris. But you could still install JVM provided by IBM for Liberty from PassportAdvantage.